# How to make a Pin pritection thing for an ATM in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

Okay so I have done most of the work but my pin code isn't working properly. You can enter a code but I want it to be you can only enter e.g 1234 to get in as so far you can but any number and get it, I tried using an else statement but I cant get it to work, any help? Also does anyone know how I could write this stuff to a file, for example, your write your name e.g joe, it finds your balance etc maybe I could do this with the pin too? not sure need some help, thanks

balance = float(0)

userInput = None

pin = int(input('Please enter the 4 digit pin on your card:'))

if pin == (1234):
        print('Correct pin!')

print "Hello, welcome to the ATM"

while userInput != "4":

```
userInput = raw_input("\n what would you like to do?\n\n     (1)Check balance\n     (2)Insert funds\n" +

"     (3)Withdraw funds\n     (4)Exit the ATM\n" )




if userInput == "1":

    print "your balance is", "£" , balance

elif userInput == "2":

    funds = float(raw_input("Enter how much money you want to add"))

    balance = balance + funds

elif userInput == "3":

    withdraw = float(raw_input("Enter how much money you want to withdraw..."))

    balance = balance - withdraw

elif userInput == "4":

    print "Thanks for using the ATM!"
```

Comment: Same you or same homework?  I've seen this exact ATM question this week already ;-)

Comment: @JLPeyret lmao, help a student out bro.

Comment: @JLPeyret They're all over the place. By now, I have a full folder of lazy students' python homework that I/we have done for them :D

Comment: @jDo Have you done an ATM yet? I could really use it lol

Comment: @Pleasehelp Nah, actually not. The ATM assignments on SO were all solved by someone else so I didn't have a reason to post. You should be able to find numerous examples on the site though. Isn't there something ATM-ish in the "Related"-column to the right? Otherwise, [search for it](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+atm) You should fix your code highlighting and indentation btw.

Comment: Duplicate of [how do i make a pin protection thing for an ATM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031676/how-do-i-make-a-pin-protection-thing-for-an-atm?rq=1)